# modelsim script on start up

Tags: modelsim, intel-fpga

I run ModelSim (Altera 13.1 SE) and I want following:
1. Load file tb.wlf
2. Add all signals to wave

**I do this:**

```
vsim tb.wlf -do "add wave -r /*"
```

**or**

```
vsim -do "vsim tb.wlf;add wave -r /*".
```

Modelsim reads all script, loads signals from tb.wlf but doesn't add to wave anything.

How can I do it? How can I make ModelSim to wait opening and then add all to wave?

Answer (score 1):

I tried in my project using tcl script. (using ModelSim PE 10.4c)

script.tcl:

```
vsim tb.wlf

add wave -r /*
```

So you have two steps: at first you run vsim with your .wlf file, after that Modelsim executes the add wave command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load an existing WLF file and then add all signals, you can do

```
vsim -view tb.wlf -do "add wave -r /*"
```

Please notice that it will only work if the WLF has the signals, i.e., you told ModelSim to log their value. If you haven't, you can do so by doing

```
vsim -wlf tb.wlf -do "log -r *; run 1 ms"
```

to run for 1 ms for example.